# How to connect 100 random points on a ring through the shortest path?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to generate 100 random points on a ring and connect them through the shortest path. The appropriate ordering function is also needed.

It should look like this:
[image]

and then this:
[image]

Could someone help me with the problem?

Comment: Have you already seen `FindCurvePath[]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1234];
a1 = Annulus[{0, 0}, {0.8, 1}]
pts = RandomPoint[a1, 100];
path = FindShortestTour[pts][[2]];
Graphics[{
  GrayLevel[0.9]
  , a1
  , Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@pts
  , GrayLevel[0.5], AbsoluteThickness[2]
  , Line[pts] 
  }
 , Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{
  GrayLevel[0.9]
  , a1
  , Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@pts
  , GrayLevel[0.5], AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[pts[[Most@path]]] 
  }
 , Frame -> True]
```

[image]